# Using Slashes In Url’s?

Tags: ghost-blog

This is my first time using Ghost, and I installed the latest version for the first time yesterday.

I have a site which has links like:
site.com/2010/03/03/post-name

I tried to manually edit the URL when posting them, but it changed it to:
site.com/2010-03-03-post-name

I tried to look around and I found out that you can use /year/month/date on the URL, but that impacts all URLs. Not all of my old URL’s are on that format, but there are some of them which are very important in this case.

So my question is:
Is it possible to change the URL structure of SOME posts with the date, and some with default format?

I am tired of searching, and if I can’t find a way, I am just going to redirect the old URLs to the new ones.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do those posts need to live on those URLs? You can use [custom collections](https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/handlebars-themes/routing/collections/) to rewrite some posts depending on the tag they have applied, however I think it would be better if you went down the alternative route and redirecting those URLs to newer and more consistent ones. Ghost has a built in redirects feature which you can read up on here:
https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/handlebars-themes/routing/redirects/